# Customer-specific prices with Algolia

Tags: php, algolia, shopware

I´m developing an open source plugin for Algolia and Shopware (https://github.com/synonymous1984/SwAlgolia).

My problem now is, that we have the following Scenario for one of our customers:

- Product **prices are calculated based on different parameters** like combinations of **customer ID, customer group, article group, manufacturer etc.**

So this means that (in theory) each customer can have his own, unique price for every product.

As it´s impossible to get all prices pre-calculated to an Algolia index (or many indices) the way I plan to go is to **only send product data to Algolia** and do the **price calculation as server-side Ajax request** as soon as the search-result returns from Algolia.

I´m not really happy with this solution but I haven´t found another way to go at the moment.

**Maybe someone of you have a better or another idea how to solve this problem??**

Thanks in advance,
best,
Synonymous

Comment: Moved to algolia discourse: https://discourse.algolia.com/t/customer-specific-prices-with-algolia/233